# Can we pass out Data in getSelection method Javascript?

Tags: selection

How can I find the start and end index of the selected text? I am using getSelection() but the issue is i am fetching data from the database and on that data, i want to find the start and end index not from DOM and getSelection() anchor offset and focus offset consider DOM to pick indexes. so how will do that?

Comment: First of all, if you are doing anything in javascript it does not matter whether it came from the database, from a static HTML file, or generated output text from some script, if it's sent to the browser it's already part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I tried to understand your problem you have some text on your webpage (doesn't matter where it originated from), you are selecting a part of it using mouse selection and trying to get a unique starting and ending index for the selected text so that you can reach out to the selected text in future.

```
function getSelectedTextIndex(){
    let selectedText = getSelection().toString();
    let paragraph = getSelection().anchorNode.data;
    let starting_index = paragraph.indexOf(selectedText);
    let end_index = starting_index + selectedText.length;
    console.log('Starting index : ', starting_index);
    console.log('End index : ', end_index);
}
```

**Note this function will print unique index for selected text with respect to the anchor node content**

for example, you have a DOM like below

```
<div>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <h2>dollar sit amet</h2>
</div>
```

and you select dollar and run this function then it should print 0,7 as anchorNode will pick h2 as anchorNode and not the content inside `<h1>`

Comment: it matters sir because indexes are not matching from original data. getSelection takes data from DOM and I have to find index from the original data. when i am printing both data there is a lot of difference between both data.